# Tikz, semicolon and missing character

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

Consider the following MWE, compiled with xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{boite/.style={draw,text width=14em,text badly centered}};
  \tikzset{liaison/.style={
        ->,thick,>=latex
    }};
  \node[boite]{foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I read this answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326089/7712
we always need a semicolon after a tikzcommands;

BUT in my case I get `Missing character: There is no ; ("3B) in font nullfont!` in the log. It if delete the semicolons after tikzset, I don't get anymore.

Where is the bug ? In my code? In fontspec? In tikz? In the answer ?

Comment: We need a semicolon at the end of a `path`.

Comment: See section "Syntax for Path Specifications" in the pgf manual (p. 153, v.3.1.10).

Comment: All and only paths are terminated with a `;`. (This includes for example `\node` because it's just a shortcut to `\path node`.) You don't need a `;` after everything else, certainly not after `\tikzset{…}`. Various packages/libraries may define additional macros/constructs that also expect a `;` at the end (e.g. `\calendar` from the `calendar` library). This may also true for external additions to TikZ.

Comment: So the answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326089/7712  is false :)

Comment: It is not false per sé, just a bit imprecise. The answer probably doesn't consider `\tikzset` to be a "TikZ command" as such, because it does not draw anything. In most situations you would also put `\tikzset` _outside_ of `\begin{tikzpicture}\end{tikzpicture}` (that would also be advisable in your example code here), reinforcing the notion that it is not part of the drawing and therefore does not need semicolons. However I agree that the linked answer as it is should be clarified as it currently is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Marijn well, a style may depend of one figure, so having tikseet inside a tikzpicture seems more logical. In my current use I have 6 figure, all of them having a different meanings, and so diffeerent style.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need multiple `\tikzset` commands and they shouldn't be ended by `;` anyway.

Rather, define the styles in the optional argument to `tikzpicture` (or in the preamble with `\tikzset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  boite/.style={draw,text width=14em,text badly centered},
  liaison/.style={->,thick,>=latex},
]
\node[boite]{foo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

ONLY to confirm [Qrrbrbirlbel comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703266/tikz-semicolon-and-missing-character#comment1749477_703266), deleting or commenting out the `semicola ;` in the non-path statements compiles fine with `XeLaTeX`.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{boite/.style={draw,text width=14em,text badly centered}}%;
  \tikzset{liaison/.style={
        ->,thick,>=latex
    }}%;
  \node[boite]{foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```